# Почему в .NET реализованы не все WinApi функции?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

Во всех книжках пропагандируют управляемый код и говорят, что в неуправляемый код практически не придется окунаться.

Однако, некоторых WinApi аналогов нету в .NET=> приходится лезть в неуправляемый код, оборачивать библиотеку и изобретать велосипед.

Вроде, у майков есть и все исходники и ничего им мешать не должно, что бы перенести весь WinApi .NET, но по какой-то причине часть мощных функций так и остались в WinApi...

Comment: Пропагандировать они могут все что угодно, однако же С/C++ быстрее и имеют доступ к любым потрохам.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов не настолько быстрее, чтобы компенсировать скорость разработки, время на отладку и тестирование и стоимость хороших специалистов по С++, а их на каждом углу что-то не валяется. На ассеблере программа будет еще быстрее и эффективнее, но почему-то на нем пишут только критические секции, к чему бы это?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов и дабы не разводить холивар, я не хаю ни си ни плюсы, хотя есть за что, как и .net. Просто ИМХО, цели и задачи должны определять необходимые инструменты, а не наоборот.

Comment: @rdorn И часто ли у вас получается на асме писать код лучше чем на сях? Да, задача в вопросе - доступ к WinAPI. И тут сишечка под задачу более чем.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов эм... а задачи более высокого порядка мы не рассматриваем? ну да ладно. Разница на самом деле не существенна, т.к. и в си нужно написать пару лишних строк для импорта функций из DLL. Единственный бонус си в данном случае в том, что часть работы за вас сделали предоставив *.h файлы к этим DLL. По поводу асма: более эффективное решение есть почти всегда, вопрос в объеме работы и необходимых знаний, по сравнению с решением той-же дачи на любом языке более высокого уровня, и именно этот фактор побудил в свое время создавать языки высокого уровня.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов впрочем, вашу позицию я понял, переубеждать не стану. Сомневаюсь что вы работали с железками в которых каждый байт и такт на счету, иначе вопрос про эффективность асма не возник бы.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

То, что в каких-то книгах пропагандируется чисто managed код - это просто маркетинговый ход.

Дело в том, разработчики .NET не ставили себе цель полностью заменить WinAPI.

Основная идея .NET - предоставить новую, более простую и удобную платформу для разработки, оставив при этом совместимость с существующими платформами - прежде всего, WinAPI и COM.

В определенных случаях это может быть достаточно близко к реальности - например в web-разработке вы скорее всего P/Invoke не увидите. Но при разработке под десктоп (особенно под WinForms) или под не-веб сервер вы будете регулярно натыкаться на на P/Invoke.

Более того, со временем вы поймете, насколько тонок уровень абстракции, предоставляемый .NET, и насколько мало управляемый код отличается от неуправляемого.

Answer (score 9):

Вообще интересный вопрос, который скорее относится к тому, *почему* .NET Framework такой какой он есть. И ответ очевидно нужно искать в том времени когда он создавался. А создавался он в попытке сделать "лучше чем Java", и в какой-то степени им это удалось. Например, локализация, работа с датой/временем/таймзонами в .NET сразу было сделано на лучшем уровне (воспоминания многолетней давности, вероятно сейчас ситуация уже изменилась). Во времена .NET 1.0/1.1 набор классов/методов вообще смотрелся довольно бледно по сравнению с WinAPI, с тех пор стало намного полнее.

С самых первых версий дотнета был Interop и P/Invoke, который собственно позволяет вызвать WinAPI, и собственно что в этом плохого? Я бы не сказал что это изобретение велосипеда -- вы же просто вызываете внешнюю функцию в неуправляемом коде, единственное -- сделайте это правильно, вот и всё.

Дальше нужно уже видимо говорить предметно -- чего конкретно нехватает, каких функций.

Напомню про список:
**Microsoft Win32 to Microsoft .NET Framework API Map**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302340.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Изначально .NET действительно создавался как альтернатива Java после очередных разборок с Sun Microsystems, по поводу того, что улучшения и изменения внесенные Microsoft в виртуальную машину Java для Windows, привели к несовместимости Java-кода на разных платформах, что противоречит идеологии Java.

Т.к. .NET довольно долго даже не пытались сделать кроссплатформенным, и даже сейчас он таковым является весьма условно, то со временем, для наиболее распространенных вызовов Win API, на тот момент единственного Win32, в .NET были включены готовые оболочки. Редко используемые функции всегда можно подключить руками, когда это понадобится.

Не углубляясь в детали и различия, .NET, как и Java, является виртуальной машиной. Это позволяет с одной стороны забыть о аппаратных различиях платформ, с другой накладывает ряд существенных ограничений, в частности, на прямой доступ к "железу". Значительная часть API, это библиотеки функций для удобного использования низкоуровневых обращений к драйверам, устройствам и функциям ядра ОС, которые, так или иначе, зависят от аппаратной платформы. Например DirectX, к которому, кстати, до сих пор не родной оболочки в .NET, WPF не в счет, там нельзя управлять процессом рендеринга.

Answer (score 0):

Какое WinAPI, .NET должен был быть самодостаточным и кроссплатформенным.

Comment: За что минус???

Answer (score 0):

Всё там есть. Просто скрыто.

.Net как бы язык более высокого уровня, чем cpp.

А winAPI это windows aplication program interface, говоря простым языком правила взаимодействия окон в windows.
Обойти их нельзя, на этом базируется винда.

Comment: Ну не знаю... Я вот смог найти в Net аналог CopyFileEx . Или юзай Win Api или пили велосипед...

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms127964(v=vs.110).aspx думаешь как работает? вызывает тот же winAPI

Comment: я малость попутал... Вот аналога этой функции я не нашел MoveFileEx . Там есть флаг, который позволяет производить манипуляции с файлами в момент перезагрузки.